# How to refresh problems log view for each event listener in eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, view, rcp

I have an application based on eclipse RCP and have a problems log view in that.

I am facing a problem that once the errors are being logged in my error view for an event listener.

Now for another event listener, the errors in the error log view are getting appended to the previous error messages instead of refreshing the view and displaying it newly.

Please tell me how to refresh the view or delete the previous errors if a listener is selected.

Comment: Is this a view you have written or one of the standard Eclipse views? How are you adding to the view?

Comment: Its the standard eclipse problems view for which I am adding my own error messages based on the event selections.

Comment: And how are you adding to the view? Are you creating new problem markers?

Comment: Yeah.. I am creating new problem markers for different events. I am adding the views by making necessary updations in the MANIFEST.MF and creating some dependencies just like I add a console view.